HDMI monitor suddenly no longer recognized as HDMI montior
I have a problem with my HDMI Montior.
It is no longer detected as a HDMI monitor.
I have not changed anything on the Hardware and every thing worked fine before. Not sure if I had a small UBUNTU Update before this happens.
The screen is still working, but with minimal resolution. Also there is no more sound (which also is connected via HDMI).
An xrandr results in:
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 270mm x 203mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
   800x600       59.86  
   640x480       59.38  
   320x240       59.52  
   720x480       59.71  
   640x400       59.95  
   320x200       58.96  
   1024x576      59.90  
   864x486       59.92  
   720x400       59.55  
   640x350       59.77  

But please understand that this all is displayed on the very same Montior via the very same HDMI-Kabel.
I also saw in some entries, that secure boot could be a problem - However, this is already disabled on my system.
I also tried a
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

However, I only got the information:
All the available drivers are already installed.

My graphic card is a Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060.
Here is the information about my UBUNTU version:
sadi@sadi-B550-AORUS-ELITE-AX-V2:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Any Ideas, or suggestions? In case I need to provide more information, please let me know.

since yesterday I did a lot of changes. I'm not sure if the last changes that solved the problem could stand for them alone - might be there are some interactions with things I tried before. However, after the following changes the problem was gone:
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^libnvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^cuda-.*'
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

After rebooting I finally had my hdmi resolution back, as well as my hdmi-based sound. I really would like to give contribution to the page where I finally found the solutions - however, after the reboot, I was no longer able to find it again.
